# ObjectSizeEstimator in Netty 4

Tags: netty

I can't Find Class "ObjectSizeEstimator" in Netty 4. This class was in third version, which allowed to estimate the memory size used by netty, was it removed in Netty 4? If it was removed, is there a replacement for this class in Netty 4?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `MessageSizeEstimator` :

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.1.32.Final/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/MessageSizeEstimator.java